# Minicart product amount display Magento

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I have a question about the minicart for example: If I have 3 unique products in my cart with 30 of each, the minicart shows a total amount of 90.

How can I make the minicart show the number of unique products, so only 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$this->getSummaryCount()` with `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();` in your code.

> app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart.phtml

```
$_cartQty = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
if(empty($_cartQty)) {
    $_cartQty = 0;
}
```